# Помогите с сортировкой списка

Tags: delphi, сортировка, delphi-7

Не работает сортировка списка во возрастанию

```
type
  tValue = Integer;                                  
  pItem = ^tItem;                                       
  tItem = record                                    
    Value: tValue;                               
    Next: pItem;                                
  end;
  tCircleList = class
  protected
    fHead: pItem;                       
    fSize: Word;                            
  public
    property Size: Word read fSize write fSize;
    property Head: pItem read fHead write fHead;

....

procedure tCircleList.Sortirovka;
// сортирока списка по возрастанию
var
  item,itemGlobal,ItemMin: pItem;
  ItemLast: tValue;
  i,j: byte;
begin
ItemMin:=fHead;
itemGlobal:=fHead;
for i:=1 to Size do
begin
  item:=itemGlobal^.Next;
  for j:=1 to Size-i do
  begin
    if item^.Value<ItemMin^.Value then
      ItemMin:=item;
      item:=item^.Next;
  end;
  ItemLast:=itemGlobal^.Value;
  itemGlobal^.Value:=ItemMin^.Value;
  ItemMin^.Value:=ItemLast;
  Writeln(ItemGlobal^.Value);
  ItemGlobal:=ItemGlobal^.Next;
  ItemMin^.Value:=ItemGlobal^.Value;
end;
end;
```

Comment: А что отладка показывает?

Comment: не пойму в чем проблема, сортирует вот так:
Сформирован список №3 из 10 элементов:
    1    3    4    5    8    2    6    7    8   10

Сформирован отсортированный список №4 из 10 элементов:
    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    1    8    1

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, пропущена конструкция `begin .. end` после `then` в этом месте:

```
if item^.Value < ItemMin^.Value then
begin
  ItemMin := item;
  item := item^.Next;
end;
```